# Trouble understanding ServeHTTP - how does this code work?

Tags: go, web-development-server

I am studying web development in Golang (Beginner) I came across some code I played around with and I'm not too sure why it works, I looked through the library source code and docs but I only have a vague idea it still isn't clicking. Note the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type foo int

func (m foo) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Some text")
}

func main() {
    var bar foo
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", bar)
}
```

From what I understand adding **ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)** as a function method, implements the **handler interface** (if I'm saying that correctly) and now **foo** is of **type handler** as well. I also understand that **http.ListenAndServe** takes an input of type handler so that is where my variable **bar** comes into play. When I run the code and go to localhost:8080 on my browser I get "Some Text" appearing.

Question:

**How does this exactly work? How is that ServeHTTP function being accessed?**

I tried looking at the source code of the libraries but couldn't pinpoint exactly how ServeHTTP worked. I found these two pieces of code (not sure if this is applicable) that sort of gave me the idea it was implementing a function but need clarification:

```
// The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of
// ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function
// with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a
// Handler that calls f.
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

I have never seen a type declaration as the one above with HandlerFunc that has a function after the name of the type. I have also seen how methods are declared but not sure what is happening in the code above.

Comment: The `HandlerFunc` has nothing to do with your actual question (*"How is that ServeHTTP function being accessed?"*) but to clarify, it is just a normal type declaration, just as you did `type foo int` defining `foo` as being of *kind* integer so you can do `type fn func()` where `fn` is a type of *kind* func with that specific signature (no args, no return values). So `HandlerFunc` is a type whose definition is: a function with two arguments (whose types are `ResponseWriter` and `*Request`) and no return values.

Comment: ... and in Go you can define methods on *any kind* of type that you declare, so having a `ServeHTTP` method on `HandlerFunc` is no different from having it on `foo`.

Comment: ... and you're right being uncertain in your choice of words. *"invokes the **handler interface**"* is incorrect, it doesn't invoke, it *implements* the interface, these are two different things, actually "invoke an interface" is not a thing in Go. It's also not **handler interface** it's `http.Handler` interface, this is important because the former could mean anything the latter is specific and can be found in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**How does this exactly work? How is that ServeHTTP function being accessed?**

To answer this question we need to look at how `http.ListenAndServe` works:

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error {
    server := &Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    return server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Here we create a Server with given address and handler and call the ListenAndServer method, so let's take a look there:

```
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServe() error {
    addr := srv.Addr
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)})
}
```

This method just starts listening at the given address and calls the Server method with our freshly created listener, so let's follow the trail there:

```
func (srv *Server) Serve(l net.Listener) error {
    defer l.Close()
    
    ...
    
    for {
        rw, e := l.Accept()

        ...

        c := srv.newConn(rw)
        c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return
        go c.serve(ctx)
    }
}
```

From the Serve method we can see that this is the point where we accept the new connection and start handling it, in it's own goroutine.

```
// Serve a new connection.
func (c *conn) serve(ctx context.Context) {
    ...
    for {
        w, err := c.readRequest(ctx)
        ...
        serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
        ...
    }
}
```

Here we finally call the ServeHTTP method, but as we can see this is not yet our implementation of that function, but something from the standard library, so let's take a look what that serverHandler struct contains:

```
// serverHandler delegates to either the server's Handler or
// DefaultServeMux and also handles "OPTIONS *" requests.
type serverHandler struct {
    srv *Server
}

func (sh serverHandler) ServeHTTP(rw ResponseWriter, req *Request) {
    handler := sh.srv.Handler
    if handler == nil {
        handler = DefaultServeMux
    }
    if req.RequestURI == "*" && req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        handler = globalOptionsHandler{}
    }
    handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

So here it is finally: If we didn't provide any Handler the DefaultServeMux will be used. but since we provided our foo handler ServeHTTP from foo get's called.

And that's it. All of this can be found @ [***server.go***](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go)

Answer (score 8):

Go's HTTP server takes in an address to listen on, and a handler. Internally, it creates a TCP listener to accept connections on the given address, and whenever a request comes in, it:

1. Parses the raw HTTP request (path, headers, etc) into a `http.Request`
2. Creates a `http.ResponseWriter` for sending the response
3. Invokes the handler by calling its `ServeHTTP` method, passing in the `Request` and `ResponseWriter`

The handler can be anything that satisfies the `Handler` interface, which your `foo` type does:

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

The standard library also includes some conveniences, like `HandlerFunc` (which allows you to pass any `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)` and use it as a `Handler`) and `ServeMux`, which allows you to register many `Handler`s and choose which one handles which request based on the incoming request path.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant type in net/http is

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

an interface type. Any concrete type implementing this interface can be used to serve HTTP request. Your `bar` is of type `foo` and foo implements the Handler interface. If the builtin HTTP server has to handle a request it will call the ServeHTTP method of your bar.

Answer (score 0):

Type declaration in this code for

```
type foo int
```

is implementing Handler interface. We can create struct or any type to implement `ServeHTTP` method. like

```
type Foo struct{}
func (m foo) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Some text")
}
```

For implementing Handler interface or any other interface It is been required to implement all methods declared in the interface on a type which is `foo` here.

`HandlerFunc` is implementing `ServeHttp` method of `Handler` interface and hence can be passed to `http.ListenAndServe` as a handler. It can be used to create middlewares wrapping around ServeHttp.

For more information on `HanlderFunc` use go doc in terminal

> `godoc net/http HanlderFunc`