# struct receiver to outside function

Tags: go

I really don't understand this code

I think I understand how receiver work but when /foo gets requested, why that struct becomes receiver to SERVEHTTP which is never called? If this is how http works, is this typical style use of receiver?

```
main go

import "net/http"

type fooHandler struct {
    Message sstring
}

func (f *fooHandler) ServerHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte(f.Message))
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/foo", &fooHandler{Message: "Hello world"})
}
```

Comment: This might help [servehttp-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668070/how-does-servehttp-work)

Comment: thank LINK was so good  @abhijitgupta    I feel like I understand MUCH better now.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First: it should be `ServeHTTP`, not `ServerHTTP`

With `ServeHTTP` method, `fooHandler` is a struct that implements `http.Handler` interface. Because of this, you can pass `&fooHandler` to `http.Handle`, and when that URL is loaded, the `ServeHTTP` method of `fooHandler` will be called.